# Add a background image through css

Tags: html, css

I have attempted adding a sky background to my website's stylesheet, but nothing really happened.

```
body {
  background: "sky-08.jpg";
}
```

When I previewed the page, the background was white, like when I just started making my page.

Comment: try: `background: url("sky-08.jpg");`

Comment: chances are high that the relative path of your url link to the `sky` image is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be: `background-image: url("sky-08.jpg");`

This also assumes that the image file is in the same location as the CSS file (Or HTML file if it is  inline)

If the image is located under an images folder in the root directory: `background-image: url("/images/sky-08.jpg");`

Answer (score 0):

Use the background-image property. Like This:

```
body {
    background-image: url("sky-08.jpg")
}
```

You can use the background property as shorthand for all the background properties including attachment, color, image, position, and repeat. If you only want to set one of these properties it is better to use the full name. See here for more: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp